# Does the power coefficient (Cp) table consider the generator efficiency curve? FLORIS

Tags: floris

I would like to know if the FLORIS power coefficient table already considers the generator efficiency curve for each wind speed.

Answer (score 0):

FLORIS is constructed to have a fixed, wind-speed-independent generator efficiency (`generator_efficiency`) with which the power production values are multiplied before being returned to the user. In the code, this variable is called `generator_efficiency` and its value in the example input `.json` is set to `1.0`. This implicitly assumes that the generator losses are already included in the `cp` values for this NREL 5MW power curve. Note that including the generator efficiency directly in the `cp` table does allow for the inclusion of a wind-speed-dependent generator efficiency.

Also, we are not officially supporting SO for questions on floris. For future questions, I suggest you post them on https://github.com/NREL/floris/discussions.